# Android firebase adding additional fields to the statistics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

It is possible in firebase to add additional statistical information like userID, deviceID and some more things ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean Firebase Analytics?
You can set user paroperties manually:
[Set user properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties)

something like this:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_id", mUserId);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("device_id", mDeviceId);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("is_app_purcahsed", mIsAppPurchased);
```

where mUserId, mDeviceIs, mIsAppPurchased - your variables